# how to disconnect from FTP host server while still executing?

Tags: vb6, ftp

I'm using Inet1.Ocx in a vb6 project to connect to a remote host.
I was wondering, is there anything to do to disconnect from server while still executing ?
i will explain more,
i write the host name and user name and password and hit (Connect) button but i find out that i misspelled the host name, while the status of the connection (Still Connecting) i attempt to disconnect to re-write the host name, but i get a message error (Still executing the last connection) ... how can i terminate the (Last connection) while (Still executing) ?!

Answer (score 0):

Have the connection and login on a seperate form and then add a disconnect button which closes the form and the connection.

http://www.bigresource.com/VB-How-to-Close-FTP-connection-using-inet-MntXMWW4FX.html

This might help ;)